# Exclude Reading/Replacing specific files in Maven Build

Tags: maven, ant, build, resources

We are using maven for building the project. It's legacy and huge one.
We newly added few .keystore files to it's resources folder.

The problem is, once the build is done, the .keystore files are getting tampered [may be maven is trying to replace/search for some placeholders]. Since it's legacy one, the project structure is so much messed up and we don't have separate distributions or no other choice but to go with plain build.

What I want is, tell maven to copy these sort of files without touching them and keeping the build as usual like before.

Between, there's no explicit  is mentioned in pom.xml, tried to doing with that as per this http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html but it's messing up the project build.

I don't want to tamper the build, since it's legacy and huge one. We are using Ant plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch off filtering for the respective `<resource/>` or add an `<exclude/>` for it.

Answer (score 0):

After going through lot of sources, Found the solution http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html

Thanks :)